# How to animate Custom Marker on Polyline instead of icon in Google Maps API V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm making a Map where my custom created marker will animate on `Polyline` from initial point to last point. Currently its working fine with "`google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE`" icon. But i want to use my custom marker instead of this "`google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE`" icon. Can someone help to do this. 
it will be great if someone help me in short time. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

For adding custom icon you have to set `icon` value in your `marker` object.

Following is sample how to add custom icon

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon:'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/location-alt-512.png',
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});
```

In `icon` youe have to give path of your custom icon.
Demo for this available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fDcV3/)

If you want to add animation on icon on click event than first add click listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
```

and in that `function` do something like that

```
if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
    this.setAnimation(null);
} else {
    this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
}
```

New demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fDcV3/2/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but its not my issue, actually I want to animate a marker on Polyline, you can check here to click on doll or cycle icon" http://lokpunjab.org/gmap/ " a icon animating fine but i need help for how i can user a marker instead od this icon to animate on that polyline.

Comment: I think you did not understand what i need. This is pretty simple you did but thanks. I explain what i want to get. you please go On this link " lokpunjab.org/gmap" . you can see i made a animation that will be run by click on cycle or doll icon. When you will click a " google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE " icon will be animate on the initial point of polyline to its last post. My question is how i can use a marker to animate on this polyline instead of "google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE". I hope now you will be understand. Thanks

Comment: when you click on `cycle icon` than small dot moves on `polyline` do you want change that small dot with custom icon?

Comment: can you post you code on JSFiddle so i can able to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Please go on this link http://jsbin.com/yosezehe/2/edit

Comment: here is example you can test that. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom
for path you have to give SVG path-image like in above example.
convert you icon image from any online tool to svg